# Typescript - object of specified type is not assignable to generic type

Tags: typescript

Conside the following simple interface and a class:

```
interface ITest{
    id :string;
}

class SuperClass<T extends ITest>{
    Start(){
        var item=<ITest>{};
        this.Do(item);
    }
    Do(item: T){
        alert(item);
    }

}
```

The line with `this.Do(item)` shows the error: `Argument of type ITest is not assignable to type T`. Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Do(item: T){
    alert(item);
}
```

The method `Do` expects a parameter of type `T`.

```
    var item=<ITest>{};
```

A variable `item` is created, of type `ITest`.

```
    this.Do(item);
```

`T` extends `ITest`, but `ITest` doesn't extend `T`. The variable item has the type `ITest`, not the type `T`.

This code compiles:

```
Start(){
    var item=<T>{};
    this.Do(item);
}
```